# The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I tried few answers already available here but still getting error,

> {     "message" : "WriteError({'code':16837,'index':0,'errmsg':'The
>   positional operator did not find the match needed from the query.
>   Unexpanded update:
>   aOrder.$.aCart','op':{'q':{'sFacebookId':'20035721279'},'u':{'$push':{'aOrder.$.aCart':{'nQuantity':1,'_id':'5b2b431632fb16084f1a9265','sItem':'Pizza
>   Margherita','nPrice':215}}},'multi':false,'upsert':false}})",     "stack"
>   : "script:1:10" }

```
var c = {
    sItem: cart.join(','),
    nPrice: sTotal,
}
User.update({ sFacebookId: sender }, {
    $push: {
        "aOrder.$.aCart": c
    }
}, { $set: { "aOrder.$.sReceiptId": sReceiptId } }, (error, result) => {
    console.log(result);
})
```

and here is my model,

```
aOrder: [{
    sReceiptId: String, 
    aCart: [{
        sItem: String,
        nPrice: Number,
        nQuantity: { type: Number, default: 1 },
    }],
    dTimestamp: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
}],
```

**// collection: users**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b2b457f5f6a6e095458668a"),
    "sFacebookId" : "2003572109654279",
    "__v" : NumberInt("0"),
    "aOrder" : [ ],
    "eStatus" : "n",
    "dCreatedDate" : ISODate("2018-06-21T11:58:15.003+05:30"),
    "sFacebookGender" : "male",
    "sFacebookName" : "John Mark"
}
```

Comment: Try without a dollar sign `aOrder.aCart` and `aOrder.sReceiptId` when specifying paths. I'm using Mongoose 4.13.12 and it worked for me and don't ask what i have to say about Mongoose documentation. This syntax is exactly the same as specified in https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/ so i'm thinking about ditching Mongoose out of the way as it's poor documentation can only lead one out of his way.